# Custom values in jQuery UI AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-option) and I'm I wonder how I can pass along custom values.

Can I use the [Option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-option) to define custom values? Not quite sure how I should use it. Currently I'm solving the "problem" by passing along the values in the URL like this:

```
source: "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/theme1/include/jquery.search.php?limit=5",
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Do you have a live demo?

Comment: No - but on this example `?limit=5` is teh key - value. Instead of passing it in the URL, I would like to pass it as an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can replace source with a function, like this

```
source : function (request, response) {
    $.get('/yoururl/', { 'q' : request.term , 'some' : 1, 'other' : 2, 'value':3 },
          function(recv) { 
              var data = eval(recv);
             //do whatever with data to build the results 
              response(data.entities); // and pass it to response
          });
};
```

Comment: I've seen this solution in a couple of examples, but thought it would be a step back using `$.get` since the `source` is kind of repalcing this.

Comment: it's a step forward in customization :) you can pass the get parameters in the url then.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

That has the source for passing data to the backend.