# autocomplete dos not show result passing custom values

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

i'm trying to pass custom values to autocomplete, so:

my custom work value's its based in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819836/custom-values-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

using a default source like doc's:

```
    $("#inpPesqCli").autocomplete({
        source: "ajax/search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        autoFocus: true
    });
```

firebug returns this (example):

```
[...
  { "id": "29083", "label": "SOME ONE 2", "value": "SOMEONE WITH LELE" },

  { "id": "19905", "label": "SOME ONE", "value": "SOMEONE WITH LALA"},
...]
```

work's perfect,  results shows up.

---

when i try to set some custom values:

```
$("#inpPesqCli").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/search.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true
});
```

firebug return's me the exactly same array result:

```
  [...
  { "id": "29083", "label": "SOME ONE 2", "value": "SOMEONE WITH LELE" },

  { "id": "19905", "label": "SOME ONE", "value": "SOMEONE WITH LALA"},
  ...]
```

but, the problem is, when i pass custom calues, the result's dosent shows up.

**php:**

```
$type = "C";
$q = strtolower($_GET["name_startsWith"]); // this i change: custom = name_startsWith / default = term

if (!$q) return;

$res = $p->SomeClass($codemp,$q,$type);

$items = array();
while(!$res->EOF){
    $items[$res->fields["NOMCLI"]]  = $res->fields["CODCLI"];
    $res->MoveNext();
}
   // below this, i have the php autocomplete default function, if u need, ask then i post.
```

dont know what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

set ajax type = GET , maybe work, by default data send type is POST

```
    $("#inpPesqCli").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/search.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type : "GET",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true
});
```